# Offline Android Dev Guide

Tags: android, reference, download, offline

I was wondering if there exists/anyone has compiled a download of the Android Dev Guide and/or the class reference pages

The pages I'm referring to are:

(the dev guide)
http://developer.android.com/guide/basics/what-is-android.html

(the class reference)
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/package-summary.html

Would be quite helpful!

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

if you install the android sdk, you can find the full documentation under android_sdk/docs (where android_sdk is the path you extracted the SDK to).  Just open up index.html.

However, the SDK documentation may need to be installed manually. You can download the documentation, if it is missing, by launching the SDK Manager located in the root directory of your SDK install location.

Comment: Not sure if it's just me, but I don't have a directory `docs` or anything like it under the subdirectories of the Android SDK installation directory. As of this writing, the latest API level is 16.

Answer (score 3):

yeah,it is at this path adnroid_sdk/docs,i found it

Answer (score 2):

For me, it was under "sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-8\docs\reference."

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed php and python on your system, you can try  converter script on github - https://github.com/phdd/android-api-guides-ebook-converter

Which downloads the latest content on the [Android developer Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide) and create a epub for you. It works fine for me. However it loss the color formatting of code blocks. Note that the converter not download the [API reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html) by default. I guess you can edit the converter script to include the API reference too (or to a separate epub file).

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you are on a MAC using the 'Android Studio' it is part of the application's resources.

Right click on the 'Android Studio' and select 'Show Packages Contents'. From there browse to 'sdk/docs/index.html' ...voila!

Answer (score 0):

For the ADT Bundle, go to the SDK Manager, open the list under the last version of android and click on "Documentation for the Android SDK

Comment: This is exactly what worked for me. It added the <path to sdk>/docs directory that everyone else has mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The Android Developer Docs is basically a less up to date mirror of the developer.android.com site distributed as a zip file.

That got me thinking and I created an Android app (https://brouken.com/offliner/) capable of reading this documentation in the source zip format. But I end up using more up to date wget mirror that includes https://material.io/ with all its javascripts and videos.